# GPU rendering of camera preview stream drop frames when using complex fragment shader

Tags: camera, gpu, shader, surface

My target device is an android 4.4.2 pad device with PowerVR GPU. Now I designed a program to retrieve the live video from camera, and then feed to GPU to do rendering, and the result is encoded as H.264 stream.

This flow is very similar with the one on bigflake: http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/CameraToMpegTest.java.txt
And I also make use of this code to do the whole staff.

Now the problem comes. I need to increase the output video resolution, for example, 2048x2048, and I also need to use a very complex fragment shader. Then I find that the app drops some frames. My incoming video is 30fps, while the outcome video averages to be 22fps, while sometime the video will seize for about one second or so.

I doubt that the GPU work load maybe too high. So I use PVRTune to profile the app workload. The ***GPU task load : tiler*** is very low, for each frame only consumes 0.4ms or so, while ***GPU task load : renderer*** is very high, for each frame it consumes 15~19ms. Other GPU task load and CPU load are all very low. During adjacent rendering frame, the GPU idle time is about 10~30ms, and it varies for each rendering frame.

I modified CameraToMpegTest.java code, put the drainEncoder() function call in an independent thread for faster processing, so my app main working loop is as follows:

```
while (System.nanoTime() < desiredEnd) {
    mnGPUOpCount++;

    // Acquire a new frame of input, and render it to the Surface.  If we had a
    // GLSurfaceView we could switch EGL contexts and call drawImage() a second
    // time to render it on screen.  The texture can be shared between contexts by
    // passing the GLSurfaceView's EGLContext as eglCreateContext()'s share_context
    // argument.
    mStManager.awaitNewImage();
    mStManager.drawImage();

    // Set the presentation time stamp from the SurfaceTexture's time stamp.  This
    // will be used by MediaMuxer to set the PTS in the video.
    if (VERBOSE) {
        Log.d(TAG, "present: " + ((st.getTimestamp() - startWhen) / 1000000.0) + "ms");
    }
    mInputSurface.setPresentationTime(st.getTimestamp());

    // Submit it to the encoder.  The eglSwapBuffers call will block if the input
    // is full, which would be bad if it stayed full until we dequeued an output
    // buffer (which we can't do, since we're stuck here).  So long as we fully drain
    // the encoder before supplying additional input, the system guarantees that we
    // can supply another frame without blocking.
    if (VERBOSE) Log.d(TAG, "sending frame to encoder");
    mInputSurface.swapBuffers();
}
```

If the fragment shader can not be optimized anymore, and the resolution remains very large, the GPU render time would be as much as 19ms. Under such condition, Can I get fluent video rendering? I think for 30fps we have 33ms operation time, so it is very possible to achieve. So what causes the frame dropping? I have no idea how to further improve the main working loop.

Comment: Update it and wish more people could see this question.

Comment: Is there someone can give me a hint?